# make a loading window till it switches to the main browser?

Tags: javascript, html, using

How to create a waiting window while the main page is loading.
basically when we  login some time is taken to load the page but since there is no change. So I want to create a window that shows loading till the page is being opened. I want to create using html or JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Loading Screen while page loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253391/javascript-loading-screen-while-page-loads)

Comment: Have you tried anything ? You will find many solutions for this problem..

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853662/how-to-show-page-loading-div-until-the-page-has-finished-loading