# Change Background on ID load

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to know how can I change my background on Id load. Right now the background is set to a colour for the preloader. I have figured out how I can hide the loader on body load but someone help me on how to change my background to a picture. Also eve when the loader is present the elements of the body popup so any solution to hide that? The background link is in the background 1 id.

> https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEMJ1DP31QMZ

```js
function hidespinner() {
  document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('heading').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('background1').style.display.backgroundImage = 'url(https://s28.postimg.org/rbexyjiil/IFBAKGROUND1.jpg)';
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #ace5f4;
  background-size: cover;
}

#spinner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
}

#spinner .inner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}

#spinner .inner:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#spinner .inner:nth-child(2) {
  border-left-color: #3bb3ee;
  border-right-color: #3bb3ee;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

#spinner .inner:nth-child(3) {
  border-top-color: #34abdb;
  border-bottom-color: #34abdb;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}

#heading {
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
}

#background1 {
  background: url(https://s28.postimg.org/rbexyjiil/IFBAKGROUND1.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/222/222506.png">

<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

<!-- Fonts Awesome CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body onload="hidespinner()">
  <h1 id="heading"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i> v<strong>Crew</strong></h1>
      <div id="spinner">
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
      </div>
      Hello Is the spinner on?
</body>
```

Please see that even the current code is copyrighted. I would also like to add this loader which I made to the page so can anyone suggest something on how to add it or add it to the webpage and give me the code.

> https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEAZZM840UQS

```js
function hideloader() {
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spirax');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Spirax');

body {
  background-color: #58e8f8;
}

.silly {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Indie Flower"
}

.spinner {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.double-bounce1,
.double-bounce2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: sk-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.double-bounce2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-bounce {
  0%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0)
  }
}

@keyframes sk-bounce {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  }
```

```html
<title>Page Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/88CE1C4C-84C0-9E49-A763-9D3DCEC43907/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<body onload="hideloader">
  <h1 class="silly"> vCrew </h1>

  <div id="loading" class="spinner">
    <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
    <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Would this work w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEMJIZCDHJBW ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :) But keep in mind that SO is a community that helps, so please show us some code you messed up with and we'll be glad to help improve it...

Comment: You might need to use some Javascript.

Comment: I created this in response to another loading-related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25253988/1762224

Comment: First of all: 
`document.getElementById('background1').style.display.backgroundImage = 'url(https://s28.postimg.org/rbexyjiil/IFBAKGROUND1.jpg)';
`
I think the `.display` shouldn't be there. It's a property itself, like `backgroundImage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a loading div on top of your content and hide/show the loading sequence until your data is present.

```js
onReady(function() {
  toggleClass(document.getElementById('page'), 'hidden');
  toggleClass(document.getElementById('loading'), 'hidden');
});

function onReady(callback) {
  var intervalID = window.setInterval(function checkReady() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
      window.clearInterval(intervalID);
      callback.call(this);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

// http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/
function toggleClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) el.classList.toggle(className);
  else {
    var classes = el.className.split(' ');
    var existingIndex = classes.indexOf(className);
    if (existingIndex >= 0) classes.splice(existingIndex, 1);
    else classes.push(className);
    el.className = classes.join(' ');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #FFF url("http://i.imgur.com/KheAuef.png") top left repeat-x;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT", cursive;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

#loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.9);
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnyxU.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bgrins/loremjs/master/lorem.js"></script>
<div id="page" class="hidden">
  <h1>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage</h1>

  <div class="content" data-lorem="7s"></div>
</div>
<div id="loading"></div>
```