# How to handle "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first."?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How to handle “Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.” with Chrome 85? I'm trying to use autoplay (with a jquery plugin).

HTML code:

```
<audio loop id="scrollaudio" src="sound/stranger.mp3"></audio>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script> $(function() { var first = new AudioFade('#scrollaudio', 100, 3300, 700).init();
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() { { var context = new AudioContext(); // Setup all nodes ... });
```

How can i fix this in a way that the user interact with the page first? Thanks to all.

Comment: when do you call `.play`?

Answer (score -1):

make a loading screen that the user has to click before going into the site, that way you now access to play audio as you please on the page. I did it that way here: https://www.tochibedford.com

Comment: thank you so much! can you help me with that? I'm so sorry but I'm really a n00b. :( can you show me the code?

Comment: hi, check this SO answer. it's pretty easy I promise. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25253988/9094171  - cheers

Comment: i'm so sorry to annoy you again but in that case it don't have a button to make the user interact with the page. :( how can i do it? thank you so much.